# How to calculate consensus of probabilistic forecasts?

Tags: forecasting

Suppose a group of forecasters each made a probabilistic forecast, for example:

Forecaster 1:

- 40% probability that company ABC will add 2 - 3 million subscribers
- 20% probability 3 - 4 million subscribers
- 20% probability 1 - 2 million subs
- 10% < 1 million subs
- 10% > 4 million subs

Forecaster 2:

- 20% probability > 2 million subs
- 50% 1 - 2 million subs
- 30% < 1 million subs

Etc...

How can I find the consensus forecast? Something like:

- Consensus expected sub addition is X
- Consensus probability of X% that sub addition will be between  A and B, C and D

Answer (score 1):

If you can ensure that your forecasters use the same bins ("<1", "1-2", "2-3", "3-4", ">4"), you can simply average probabilities within each bin between the forecasters. These average probabilities will still add up to 100%, so they are *bona fide* probabilities, and you can report the expectation or the median of the averaged probability distribution as a consensus point forecast.

If your forecasters have different bins, like in your example (forecaster 2 uses a bin ">2", which forecaster 1 subdivides into three bins "2-3", "3-4", ">4"), you will need to map the forecasts to a common grid. In your example, you could subdivide forecaster 2's bin ">2" into forecaster 1's three bins and divide forecaster 2's assigned probability of 20% equally into 6.67% for each one of the smaller bins, then proceed as above.

If you are only interested in certain fixed quantiles, you can work *ad hoc*. For instance, the median for forecaster 1 is "3-4" and for forecaster 2 it is "1-2", so you could reasonably report a consensus median of "1-4" or "2-3" - either one would be defensible, and to be honest, with the coarse grids your forecasters use and the probabilities that are always multiples of 10%, I wouldn't worry too much about getting fancy in combining the forecasts.

Comment: So I take it whenever possible, ensure all forecasts use predefined bins.

Comment: And are there better ways to collect these forecasts? I don't know if the bins approach is the most appropriate. The goal is to find the consensus, but I also want to show the variability of the forecasts and possibility of rare events. Thanks.

Comment: One alternative would be to do it the other way around: ask your forecasters for a mean forecast, as well as 25% and 75% prediction quantiles (possibly even 10% and 90%). The [Survey of Professional Forecasters](https://www.philadelphiafed.org/research-and-data/real-time-center/survey-of-professional-forecasters/) by the Philadelphia Fed has been doing this for decades. You may want to dig through their website on how they combine the individual quantile forecasts.